# How to disable MemCached timeout in Werkzeug

Tags: python, memcached, werkzeug

Is it possible to set the timeout for MemCached values to infinite (disable it) in Werkzeug?

I tried the following:

```
    cache = MemcachedCache(['127.0.0.1:11211'], default_timeout=None)
```

This gives an error. If I do this:

```
    cache = MemcachedCache(['127.0.0.1:11211'], default_timeout=0)
```

It literally gives it a default_timeout of 0 seconds and nothing is stored. How can I set the default_timeout such that it gets disabled?

Comment: I had a look at the source code, and it seems there is nothing you can do to disable the timeout. default_timeout is added to the current time when setting a value, hence why it immediately expires

Comment: There is an open feature request on this https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/issues/550

Comment: I updated the code and created a pull request https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/pull/725